# Windows 10 - How to avoid the switch to virtual desktop

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I have a very irritating problem,with an Asus K73SD.

When I move the pointer with the touchpad,it's like I'm trying to change "virtual"

desktop.

All open browser windows getting smaller at the center of the screen.

To avoid this issue I tried to change the touchpad settings,but nothing happend.

It happens quite often,but I don't know how to fix this issue.

For example,I don't know how to check if the touchpad drivers work correctly or

if there are updates.

Can,please,someone help me to understand what can be done?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, ubu16.  I don't have an answer for you, but your question is a little like haiku.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234,Hi,I'll try to explain my "haiku" question with other words.Immagine to be somewhere,with the pointer,on a web page and you need to change page,which means moving your pointer upper left to the bookmarks,during this pointer movement (sometimes for 2/3 times)all your open web pages getting smaller in the center of your screen.As I said,it's like when you want to change  virtual desktop.But I don't want it,I want to avoid it.Thank you

Comment: When you start moving your finger, do you start at the edge of the trackpad? Are any keyboard keys possibly stuck? Maybe try uninstalling the synaptics driver if you have one?

Comment: @Steve,yes,if I start at the edge of the trackpad I have the issue described above.But I don't have any issue with keyboard keys.I have synaptics PS/2 Port touchpad and it seems to work well.But honestly,as I said,I don't know how to check it correctly.Have you some suggestions to give me?Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Are you using only one fingertip on the touchpad? It sounds like you might be using [all four fingertips](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027871/windows-10-touchpad-gestures).

Comment: ,it's true I feel more comfortable with only a fingertip.From your linked gesture guide,with four finger you can switch virtual desktop(it doesn't work on my laptop).But,I **don't** want switch virtual desktop.Thank you